# Choosing the paper size

Tags: paper-size

Miktex generated a PDF file with dimensions 8.27 x 11.69 inches. Is there any way to "fix" it to 8.5 x 11 inches, the US Letter default printing size?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96489/miktex-default-papersize-setting

Comment: The [corresponding section of the MiKTeX Manual](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/papersize.html) should help here.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)